# Computing a hash for a street

Tags: java, hash, geolocation, geocoding, geospatial

I'm facing a little geolocation problem. I have `Street {name, lat, long}` and I wish to construct a hash that returns the same value for a particular street name within about 500-1000m radius of `[lat, long]`. I don't really care too much about the length of the hash.

Additional info: this `[lat, long]` would be obtained via mobile devices (GPS).

**EDIT**: I've thought about truncating digits off the end of the `lat` and `long` but that doesn't take care of cases like `[7.499999, 7.599999]`

**EDIT 2**: Rounding to the nearest hundredth seems to be better but also presents some edge cases.

How would you go about this?

Comment: What you're describing can't be done.  Having the same hash code is an equivalence relation.  But being within 500-1000m of somewhere is not transitive.

Comment: @DavidWallace Any approximate that might not necessarily be correct 100% of the time? Please see my edit if you know about any possible improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should approach the probelm another way. I assume you would want a hash so that the streets that are closer to a specified long, lat are at the top.

If, so put the street name, long, lat in an object that is comparable

```
public class Location
{
    String street;
    long longitude;
    long latitude;
}
```

Then create a Comparator for this object

```
public class LocationComparator implements Comparator
{
    long someLongitude;
    long someLatitude;

    public LocationComparator(long someLongitude, long someLatitude)
    {
        this.someLongtitude = someLongitude;    
        this.someLatitude = someLatitude;

    }

    public int compare(Location obj1, Location obj2)
    {
        // get distance from obj1 to someLongtitude, someLatitude
        // get distance from obj2 to someLongtitude, someLatitude

        // return -1, 0, 1 accodring to distance for obj1, obj2
    }
}
```

Then sort the list with

```
LocationComparator comparator = new LocationComparator(someLongitude, your someLatitude);
Collections.sort(LocationsList, comparator);
```

Comment: Actually, that's not the use case. I want to be able to uniquely identify a street by only it's name and co-ordinates. I know that can be many "Sesame" streets but I assume that there should be only one within about 1km radius.

Comment: ah, ok nvm, though I would have thought the one at the top of the list would be the street closest to your location.

Comment: But that would mean I retrieve "streets" from a datastore, exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I do not want to worry whether the street already exists in the datastore and even if it does, I do not want to bother retrieving it. I just want to blindly store a hash that could then be used to retrieve other landmarks.

Comment: It may or may not interest you to know that, for historical reasons, the city that I live in contains two entirely separate streets, both called Victoria Street, that come within just under 1km of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I would truncate `lat` and `long` in the way you describe and then just use

```
Objects.hash(name, truncatedLat, truncatedLong)
```

Using truncated values of `lat` and `long` is the same as considering only certain key locations

```
X    X    X    X

X    X    X    X

X    X    X    X
```

Given a triple `(name, lat, long)`, you would not be guaranteed to get the same hash by truncating `lat` and `long`, because the street may be near to several crosses `X`. However I don't think this is a problem, as it just means that to find a street in a `HashMap` you would probably have to search several of the closest crosses `X`.

Comment: @SayoOladeji I've read the edits. What's wrong with this answer? David Wallace's comment is right. There is simply no way to guarantee getting the same hash every time. Something like I've described would work though.

Comment: I thought you perhaps didn't see EDIT 2. There's nothing wrong per se with this answer.

Comment: I have read edit 2. I don't get your point. No matter what scale you use there are always going to be edge cases because you are trying to replace a point in continuous space by a discrete value. I would just ensure that the crosses are separated by about 500m and then just accept you may have to search search, say, 25 or more crosses before you find the entry.

Comment: I agree with you that there will always be edge cases. I'm only wondering if it's possible that an improvement be made (even if it just improves results by 1%). Your answer and explanation is good and I really appreciate you taking the time to provide them.

Comment: Well, your problem is all about dividing your region down into patches, where all locations within each patch have the same hash code.  Using truncated values will give you little rectangular patches.  It's not clear what kind of scheme you would consider to be an "improvement" on this.